# Type error cannot read properties of undefined while trying to access a class property created by a class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, class, undefined

Im havving trouble building an express api in TS node.
Im new at express and im learning Node, JS and TS since 2022 so im sorry if the question is not to complex.
The thing is that im tryng to build a class Controller that handles the needed instructions for every route in my express router.
And im passing through the constructor a DAO that ive builded to access the firebase firestore database.
But when i instanciate the object and i try to run it Gives me the cannot read properties of undefined error.
Even when ive found a solution by using a clousure i want to learn how to do this using classes
Here it is the code of the DAO

```
import { setDoc, doc, getDocs, collection, query, where, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
import { DataResponse, GenericItem } from '../types'
import { DAO } from '../clases/abstractClasses'
import { v4 } from 'uuid'
import db from '../config/firebase'
// import fs from 'fs/promises'
const fs = require('fs').promises
const storage = getStorage()
export class DataResponseClass implements DataResponse {
  data: GenericItem[]
  status: number
  statusText: string
  err: string
  ok: boolean
  constructor (data: GenericItem[], status: number, statusText: string, err: string, ok: boolean) {
    this.data = data
    this.status = status
    this.statusText = statusText
    this.err = err
    this.ok = ok
  }
}
export class DbManager extends DAO {
  constructor (collectionRef: string) {
    super(collectionRef)
  }

  async addItem (item: GenericItem): Promise<DataResponse> {
    const id = v4()
    console.log(id, typeof id)
    return await setDoc(doc(db, this.collectionRef, id), { ...item, id }).then(res => {
      return new DataResponseClass([{ ...item, id }], 201, 'Item added successfully', '', true)
    }).catch(err => {
      return new DataResponseClass([item], 400, "Couldn't add item", err.toString(), false)
    })
  }

  async getAll (): Promise<DataResponse> {
    return await getDocs(collection(db, this.collectionRef)).then(response => {
      const dataArray: any = []
      response.forEach(item => dataArray.push(item.data()))
      return new DataResponseClass(dataArray, 200, 'Information obtained', '', true)
    }).catch(err => new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Couldnt Retrieve data', err.toString(), false))
  }

  async getById (passedId: string): Promise<DataResponse> {
    const q = query(collection(db, this.collectionRef), where('id', '==', passedId))
    return await getDocs(q)
      .then(res => {
        const dataArray: any[] = []
        res.forEach(item => {
          dataArray.push(item.data())
        })
        if (dataArray.length === 0) throw new Error('No data found for the id')
        return new DataResponseClass(dataArray, 200, 'Information obtained', '', true)
      })
      .catch(err => new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Couldnt Retrieve data', err.toString(), false))
  }

  async updateById (id: string, item: GenericItem): Promise<DataResponse> {
    return await setDoc(doc(db, this.collectionRef, id), item)
      .then(() => new DataResponseClass([{ ...item, id }], 200, 'Item succesifuly updated', '', true))
      .catch(err => new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Couldnt update item', err.toString(), false))
  }

  async deleteByid (id: string): Promise<DataResponse> {
    return await deleteDoc(doc(db, this.collectionRef, id))
      .then(() => new DataResponseClass([], 200, 'Success deleting a document', '', true))
      .catch(err => new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Couldnt Delete data', err, false))
  }

  async upLoadFile (file: Express.Multer.File | undefined): Promise<string> {
    if (file !== undefined) {
      const buffer = await fs.readFile(file.path).then()
      const reference = ref(storage, `/${this.collectionRef}/${file.filename}`)
      try {
        await uploadBytes(reference, buffer)
        return await getDownloadURL(reference)
      } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err)
        return 'There was an error uploading the file'
      }
    }
    return 'No file was uploaded'
  }
}
```

And this is the Controller class code..

```
import colors from 'colors'
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { DbManager, DataResponseClass } from '../services/firebase'
import fs from 'fs/promises'
export class Controller {
  protected readonly dbManager: DbManager
  constructor (collection: string) {
    this.dbManager = new DbManager(collection)
  }

  async readData (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const id: string = req.params.id
    if (id !== undefined) {
      res.send(await this.dbManager.getById(id))
    } else {
      res.send(await this.dbManager.getAll())
    }
  }

  async createData (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    if (req.file !== undefined) {
      const uploadedFilePath = await this.dbManager.upLoadFile(req.file)
        .then((response: any) => {
          console.log(`${response}/${req.file?.filename || ' '}`)
          if (req.file?.path !== undefined) {
            fs.unlink(req.file.path).then(() => console.log('Upload Complete')).catch(err => console.log(err))
          }
          return `${response}`
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(err)
          res.send(false)
        })
      const data = { ...req.body, images: uploadedFilePath }
      console.log(colors.bgRed.white(data))
      res.send(await this.dbManager.addItem({ ...req.body, images: uploadedFilePath }))
    } else res.send(new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Invalid Request no image uploaded', 'Invalid Request no image uploaded', false))
  }

  async editData (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const { id } = req.params
    if (req.file !== undefined) {
      const uploadedFilePath = await this.dbManager.upLoadFile(req.file)
        .then((response: any) => {
          if (req.file?.path !== undefined) {
            fs.unlink(req.file.path).then(() => console.log('Upload Complete')).catch(err => console.log(err))
          }
          return `${response}`
        })
        .catch((err: { toString: () => string }) => {
          console.log(err)
          res.send(new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Imposible to upload the file', err.toString(), false))
        })
      res.send(await this.dbManager.updateById(id, { ...req.body, images: uploadedFilePath }))
    } else res.send(new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Invalid Request no image uploaded', 'Invalid Request no image uploaded', false))
  }

  async deleteData (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const { id } = req.params
    if (id !== undefined) {
      res.send(await this.dbManager.deleteByid(id))
    } else res.send(new DataResponseClass([], 400, 'Invalid Request no id', 'Invalid  Request no id', false))
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time Im tryng to learn this beautifull world that is the backend development

Ive tryed to call the constructor outside the class and pass the constant to the constructor
Ive tryed to instanciate the DAO object as a param,Ive even called the dao constructor in a global variable and defined the properti taking value from it .
But the only solution ive found for my issue es transforming the class into a clousure function and calling the constructor in the body of the closure

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dbManager')
    at /run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/src/controllers/controllerClass.ts:20:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/src/controllers/controllerClass.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/src/controllers/controllerClass.ts:4:12)
    at readData (/run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/src/controllers/controllerClass.ts:24:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/run/media/adrianabadin/code/dcsbackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[ERROR] 16:55:20 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dbManager')
```

**Routes**
Here I call the method readData

```js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { Controller } from '../controllers/controllerClass'
// import { Validation } from '../services/validation'
import { upload } from '../config/multer'
const router = Router()
// const { validate } = new Validation('welcome')
const { readData, createData, editData, deleteData } = new Controller('welcome')
router.get('/', readData)
router.get('/:id', readData)
router.post('/', upload.single('images'), createData)
router.put('/:id', upload.single('images'), editData)
router.delete('/:id', deleteData)
export default router
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: Sorry its my first real question on stack overflow. I missed that 
Ive added the error at the end of the post

Comment: What line is throwing that error exactly? And what code are you calling that triggers that error?

Comment: When i ask any request to the api. For example in  this case ive  pulled a get request so the error was triggered by the readData method

Comment: Ok, but the `readData` method isn't in your question anywhere. What does that method look like? And which line is `controllerClass.ts:20` and `controllerClass.ts:8` in your file (as mentioned in the error trace)? Your problem is that `this` isn't correctly bound, which means you're calling some function the wrong way. So how you invoke all this code is very important here.

Comment: I placed an old version of the controller ive alrready fixed.the question the method was called getController in thar version. Actually i do a destructuring of the object in 4 variables and i use those vars in the function argument of the route

Comment: _"Actually i do a destructuring of the object in 4 variables and i use those vars in the function argument of the route."_ That's potentially the whole problem. Please [edit] your question and show how that destructuring is done and how you invoke the `readData` method on your controller.

Comment: First im already thankfull for your time and dedication. 
Ive edited the question and ive placed the code of the router.
Line 7 is the destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { readData, createData, editData, deleteData } = new Controller('welcome')
```

You can't destructure normally declared instance methods from classes.

---

I'm going to vastly simplify this to this example:

```
class Foo {
    private data = 123
    getData() { return this.data }
}
```

Now if you call `getData` like so, it works:

```
const foo = new Foo()
console.log(foo.getData())
// 123
```

But if you destructure the method:

```
const { getData } = new Foo()
console.log(getData())
// Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

Then it crashes.

The value of `this` is being lost because you don't call it with a `.`, which is what provides the class instance to the function.

---

Now let's try this one:

```
class Foo {
    private data = 123
    getData = () => { return this.data }
}

const foo = new Foo()
console.log(foo.getData())
// 123

const { getData } = new Foo()
console.log(getData())
// 123
```

This works because typescript compiles property assignments in classes to happen in the constructor, and because the arrow function `=>` captures the value of this from when it was declared. So now you can break off the method and it works.

Just note that while the traditional instance method declaration is shared between all instances, this arrow function method will create a new function for every instance. This may hurt performance if you plan to create a very large number of instances. But for backend service classes like this that's probably not a concern.

---

So in your case just call the method on the instance:

```
const controller = new Controller('welcome')
router.get('/', (req, res) => controller.readData(req, res))
```

Or you declare your method as a arrow function.

```
export class Controller {
  //...
  readData = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
    const id: string = req.params.id
    if (id !== undefined) {
      res.send(await this.dbManager.getById(id))
    } else {
      res.send(await this.dbManager.getAll())
    }
  }
  //...
}

const { readData } = new Controller()
readData() // fine now
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! i passed the last 15 days reviewing this and didnt found an answer 
Ivent realized that the context of this could be the problem. 
I guess thas the reason im a Jr. :-)

Comment: Another question.... Then is more performant to continue with the aproach of a clousure funtion?

Comment: Probably because that closure function is only ever created once when the route gets mapped. But that controller is probably only ever created once. So if it's better, it's only by an astronomically small margin in most cases. So do whichever is feels cleaner to you or better follows the conventions of your existing codebase.

Comment: No problem, Adrian! And don't forget to click the checkmark by this answer to accept it if it solved your problem.